# How can disk cloning without dismounting work?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, clone, disk-cloning

When last I cloned an HDD, a few years back, the program (I forget which it was...) rebooted my machine to write the clone. I'm now doing this again but all the versions of clone software I'm seeing seem to work without rebooting, so the drive that is being cloned is still mounted, which concerns me.

Can anyone explain how the cloning program can be safe without doing that? (Especially when cloning the system drive)

Comment: Windows' Volume Shadow Copy is one of the few advantages over Linux... it creates a snapshot that allows copying the entire disk in a stable state, while allowing work to continue (though I try to let the imaging proceed unimpeded).

Comment: I see a lot of comments got deleted

Comment: Ian was cloning to upgrade a hard drive. Question asked to Ian was, what is unsafe about "volume shadow copy".. So say volume shadow copy means that IO writes are held in RAM and written after the copy. So you don't do anything important  adding important files to the hard drive while the image/clone is being made. Once the clone or image is made then you could shutdown the computer and take out the old drive.